# How to use Python keynote-parser in the Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, extract, keynote

I am trying to use an external module called keynote-parser to extract data from the a Mac Keynote file. It works when I use as command lines in the terminal on the Mac laptop locally. I am trying to extract the data and put the files/blobs into a Azure Storage (Blob/Fileshare) using the Keynote-parser. However, I am not quite sure how to write the script to include the keynote-parser and then calling. Honestly, I am stuck even having it as a local Python script even run it instead of command lines.

here is the keynote-parser
https://github.com/psobot/keynote-parser

I expected it to able to pickup a file/blob from Azure Storage (fileshare/blob) and extract the files. The script will then select the output file called Slide.iwa.yaml from the index folder it generated. The script will put the file into Azure Storage (fileshare/blob).

When having just `import keynote_parser`, no issue. However, when added `from keynote_parser import file utils`, the deployment out shows that "No HTTP triggers found"

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import keynote_parser
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobType
from keynote_parser import file_utils

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `from keynote_parser import file_utils` in my code and then published it to function app like below-

**`Code:`**

```cs
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  logging
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient,BlobType
from  azure.storage.fileshare  import  ShareClient
from  keynote_parser  import  file_utils

app  =  func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def  http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

name  =  req.params.get('name')
if  not  name:
try:
req_body  =  req.get_json()
except  ValueError:
pass
else:
name  =  req_body.get('name')
if  name:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
else:
return  func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
status_code=200
)
```

**`requirements.txt:`**

```
azure-functions
keynote-parser
azure-storage-blob
azure-storage-file-share
```

I have deployed the function and got successful deployment result.

[image]

For `No HTTP triggers found`, you can check the following-

- If you have added any connection string in function_app.py file then move it to local.settings.json file and refer it.
- Check in the function app-->Environment Variables, if `"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"` is present.

You can also refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1774) for more details on `No HTTP triggers found`.

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, my code with the import is working fine now. Not sure what happened but it works now. Anyway, thank you for trying it and showing that there is nothing wrong with this import.